# How can i learn to use Websocket on Android and can i test it even if i don't have a server?

Tags: android, websocket

We are trying to learn Websocket to send and receive information from a server. Can you suggest us links that explain how to use it easy to understand? Besides, we don't have a server yet. So can we test it even if we don't have a server? Thanks

Comment: Without a server, all you can test is what happens when the server can't be accessed...

Comment: run server software locally or on amazon aws or whatever

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Stratton stated it, run a WebSocket server locally.

For testing and getting started to WebSocket communication you can also use https://github.com/cobuChris/yak-js

Easy setup and you have a WebSocket server instance running to play around in minutes.